# How to rename a gem?

Tags: rubygems

I have a gem that I want to rename. It is [published on RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/croptoelie). I am mostly concerned about people wanting to update it.

I see two paths, but would really like to hear from people who renamed their gem, how they did this.

### 1. turn the old one into a metapackage

- Create a new gem (named `smart-cropper`)
- Add `smart-cropper` as a dependency to `croptoelie` (old gem)
- Remove all lib, bins and other code from `croptoelie`

A problem I see with this, is that it is too transparent, people might not be aware that the gem they use is no longer maintained.

Another problem is that versioning becomes harder: I would have to bump the version of the old "metapackage" each time I released a new version of the renamed (`smart-cropper`) gem, or people would never get a new version.

### 2. throw deprecation warnings

I could send out a release of the old gem that simply throws deprecation warnings with a message that people should install that new gem.

The problem I see with this is that it can be quite intrusive and might turn people[1] away from the gem altogether.

Are there other options? Is there something built into "RubyGems" to cater for the changing of the name?

[1] not that too many people are using it; because of the name it is hard to find. :)

Comment: I've never done it, but I'd vote for #2.  Seems this is the perfect case for deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*You simply push the new gem with the new name and tell your users about the new name. There is no mechanism for renaming gems.* -- [RubyGems support staff, February 20, 2012](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/questions/104-how-should-i-handle-the-rename-of-a-gem)

To that end, the following are some tips (some of which I see you have already done).

### in the old gem, throw deprecation warnings

Example:

```
warn "[DEPRECATION] This gem has been renamed to _____ and will no longer be supported. Please switch to _____ as soon as possible."
```

### in old gem's `.gemspec` file

Display a message after the old gem is installed, using the [post_install_message](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#post_install_message) attribute. The following example is based on the [Heroku gem](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/heroku.gemspec#L15-L19).

```
gem.post_install_message = <<-MESSAGE
!    The '_____' gem has been deprecated and has been replaced by '_____'.
!    See: https://rubygems.org/gems/_____
!    And: https://github.com/_____/_____
MESSAGE
```

### on the old GitHub repo's page

-1- At the top of the page: *Add a description to this repository:* (provide the new name)

```
Moved to ---> "_____".
```

-2- At the top of the page: *Add a website to this repository:* (make this the URL of the new repo)

```
https://github.com/_____/_____
```

-3- Upload a new `README.markdown`:

```
# OLD NAME

Moved to [new name](https://github.com/_____/_____).
```

-4- Consider removing all non-essential files.

### in the new gem's `.gemspec` file

Include the following notice at the end of the `summary` or `description` attribute:

```
Formerly known as '_____'.
```

### yank the old gem

At some distant point, you may want to remove the old gem from RubyGems. As of RubyGems `1.3.6` and gemcutter `0.5.0` (circa February 2010), you can use `gem yank` to *remove your gem from being available with gem install and the other gem commands.* However, the gem will still be available for download for two main reasons:

1. Other gems may have been pushed that depend on your gem.
2. A mass deletion of important community based gems can be easily prevented.

[Go here for more info about yank.](http://help.rubygems.org/kb/gemcutter/removing-a-published-rubygem)